# How to set type for () => dispatch(action) in typescript?

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux-toolkit

I am new to typescript and converting my jsx to tsx files. How can I define the type for a redux dispatch for my `onPress` prop? I tried using "Function" and the "AppDispatch". Thanks in advance

```
import { AppDispatch } from "../redux/store"


interface ItemProps {
    item: Custom_date, 
    onPress: AppDispatch, //What should I put here?
    backgroundColor: any,
    textColor: any
}

const Item = ({ item, onPress, backgroundColor, textColor }: ItemProps) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress} style={[styles.item, backgroundColor]}>
        <Text style={[styles.dateTitle, textColor]}>{item.title}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
);

export const DateHeader = () => {
    const { date } = useSelector((store: RootState) => store.nutrition)
    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        const backgroundColor = item.id === date.id ? "#033F40" : "#BDF0CC";
        const color = item.id === date.id ? '#BDF0CC' : '#033F40';

        return (
            <Item
                item={item}
                onPress={() => dispatch(setDate(item))}
                backgroundColor={{ backgroundColor }}
                textColor={{ color }}
            />
        );
    }

    return (<>
        <FlatList {props} />
    </>)
}
```

Comment: write `const test = dispatch(action)` in your component somewhere, then hover over `test`. Your editor should tell you the type inferred from that.

Comment: thank you for the tip. however, when i tried inserting the detected type. I get "property match is missing" error on my `onPress` prop. I suspect I am passing in `()=>dispatch(setDate(item))` incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only things you need to know to type a function are the argument types and the return type. In order to find the return type of `dispatch()` you can check the internals of `useDispatch()`, but as a general rule (with quite a few exceptions) click handlers will not return anything. Any side effects the function produces, such as by updating a variable or calling an API or updating a database, won't be included in the type signature.

You're also not passing in any parameters in `onPress` as you can tell from the empty brackets where you define the arrow function, which simplifies things a lot.

As a result your type for `onPress` will most likely be as follows, if the dispatch function you're calling does not return a value:

```js
interface ItemProps {
    item: Custom_date, 
    onPress: () => void,
    backgroundColor: any,
    textColor: any
}
```